# building ndk android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

i have a prebuilt libraries that contains jar files and .so files and i newly converted my project from eclipse to android studio 
my libs directory in eclipse is

libs
****armeabi

****x86

****jar files
so armeabi and x86 contains the .so files and when i converted project to android studio the app build very well at first but some classes in the .so files are not initialized and giving error

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nmsp_speex from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/project.app-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/project.app-2]: findLibrary returned null

and i searched about this error , people says that you must add .so files in jni folder and a already did that ad found build error when android studio tried to build the ndk and the error says

Error:Execution failed for task ':project:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android Index\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

and here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':pagerslidingtabstrip')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"
    defaultConfig
            {
                minSdkVersion 9
                targetSdkVersion 21
                multiDexEnabled true
            }

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jni/']
    }
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

so any help on this

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any NDK source code inside your project (you're not generating the .so files, you're only using them), then remove the jni folder and put your *.so* files into `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi` and `src/main/jniLibs/x86`.

btw you placed your ndk directory under a path that contains a space. You should move it to somewhere else or delete this blank space.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I placed my .so files under

```
src->
  main->
        jniLibs->armeabi-> .so file
```

and removed the line containing

```
jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jni/']
```

from my app's build.gradle.And it works fine.

Hope this helps someone.